# Integration of google maps into DJI mapWidget

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I am trying to develop an application for android for the DJI Mavic Air where I want to use the mapwidget. When I run the app it crashes and I get the following error:

[Error trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWIyA.png)

The error seems to happen when I call the initGoogleMap. I have called the mapwidget functions onCreate(Bundle), onResume(), onPause(), onDestroy(), onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and onLowMemory() in the corresponding methods in my app.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Google Maps API version 9.4.0 or earlier to avoid this crash. In later API versions, MapView.onStart() was added to the Google Maps API and creates a conflict with an internal method in the DJI UX SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much it seems to have solved the issue.
Now it crashes at the mapwidget's onResume() instead with a nullpointerexception

Here I get the following error message:
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bo.o()' on a null object reference"

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?